# Connect Deployment Agent to Visual Studio Online if not part of domain

Tags: .net, azure-devops, release-management, azure-virtual-machine, ms-release-management

I'm installing the Microsoft Deployment Agent 2013 onto an Azure VM. In order to connect to my Release Management Server ( Visual Studio Online in my case ) I need to authenticate either as local system or with a custom account:

[image]

So with my credentials - I am validated to use the Release Management Service, but I cannot connect with them to the Release Management Server:

```
I, 2015/02/04, 16:50:11.245, User [ME] is system, Admin  
I, 2015/02/04, 16:50:11.260, Validated account to use as identity for Release Management Services. 
I, 2015/02/04, 16:50:11.260, Validating Release Management Server for Team Foundation Server 2013... 
E, 2015/02/04, 16:50:11.448, Got a non-OK status code of NonAuthoritativeInformation from http://whatever.visualstudio.com/...
```

Of course - the credentials with which I login to the box are not the same as with which I have access to RM server. So you I figured I had 2 options:

- Add an identical account with which I have access to RM server to the local box: didn't work, my ...@hotmail.com username is too long.
- Add the credentials of the box to Visual Studio Online: didn't work, it needs to send out that invitation e-mail.

The other option is of course to use Release Management without the agent. Which uses remote powershell. That didn't work either - the deployment fails with:

```
Connecting to remote server boxcloudapp.net failed with the following error message : Access is denied. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
```

From what I read, I suspect this is because the powershell runs over SSL and offers the self signed cert to Release Management which is not trusted as root CA.

What am I doing wrong here? It can't be that hard, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Visual Studio Online you neither need a Release Management server, nor a deployment agent.

If you open up the Release Management Client and connect to https://youraccount.visualstudioonline.com you will be automatically configured for Release Management Online. You can then link the RM online server to your azure account and deploy without an agent.

http://nakedalm.com/create-release-management-pipeline-professional-developers/

Comment: Thanks - somehow the remote powershell ( Agent-less deployment ) started working. The remote powershell endpoint was already exposed, I don't know what changed. Thanks!