# Where are the actions in Release Management?

Tags: release-management, ms-release-management

I'm setting up Release Management for my application. I've succesfully published the application to the target server through powershell. However, now I'm trying to publish the database and it seems I'm missing a bunch of actions from the actions tree in the Release Template view:

[image]

This is my view - these 6 actions are all I have to work with.

For instance, looking at this tutorial, there should be a lot more actions: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/03cb49/ms-release-management-database-deployment-using-dacpac/

[image]

I'm looking for the DACPAC one, but I cannot find it. What am I doing wrong?

The 'inventory' is quite empty too - there are no inactive actions there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are seeing only 6 actions as you are working with the vNext Release Templates (agentless release templates). These templates do not support the entire suite of actions that you can see in the blog that you have mentioned.

Create a ReleasePath and not a "vNext Release Path" and select "Release Template" in the configure apps tab. You should be then able to work as per the blog.

For more details follow this [link](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/manage-your-release-vs.aspx). It contains all information about [setting up release with deployment agents](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/dn864548#SetupEnv).

Comment: Hi @divyanshm - thanks for your answer! I cannot use the agent, since I'm on Azure with VS Online. At least, that's what I understand from my other question ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28327391/connect-deployment-agent-to-visual-studio-online-if-not-part-of-domain ). So I guess the vNext releases without agent depend more heavily on PowerShell scripts.